# How to import a React component I've made locally without node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-link

I built a react component (my-shared-component) that I would like to use with other projects locally. I used rollup to bundle my component and the output is a dist folder.

In order to avoid publishing my component to npm yet, I used `npm link`. However, when I do `npm link <my-shared-component>` in my host component, the entire shared component folder is added inside my node_modules, including my component's node_modules library, source files, etc - This causes several bugs in my host app.

Obviously I don't want to do, if I had published my component to npm and then used `npm -i my-shared-component`, only my dist folder would've been installed.

I can I mimic this behavior locally using npm-link? I want to use the packaged version of my-shared-component.

Thank you!

Comment: could you do it with a regular old symlink? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Comment: can you elaborate on several bugs on your host app ?

Comment: and also npm-link create a global symlink for a dependency with npm link. A symlink, short for symbolic link, is a shortcut that points to another directory or file on your system. so, yes all your files including node_modules,source will be shared.

Comment: Would it be somehow possible to have a link to a packaged version? with npk-link I get the automatic linkage between the two. With npm-pack I get the bundled version I need. How do I combine the 2?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the case by using `npm pack` inside my `my-shared-component` and then `npm i ../.../full-path/my-shared-component-1.0.0.tgz` inside my host app.

That way I only get the packed bundled version of `my-shared-component` without the node_modules and source code.

This does mean that I have to pack my shared component every time which is not ideal. If anyone has any better solution please let me know.

Thanks